# How to fetch only the "text/plain" and "text/html" parts of an email message?

Tags: email, imap, email-client

I am trying to fetch only the text part of an email and ignore attachments using imap in python. The only way I found out to do this is by first fetching the body structure of an email, parsing it, and choosing only the parts with the text. However, I am having a really hard time parsing the body structure. I have read RFC 3501 and I might have to write code by myself to parse it but it would be really helpful if there's a MIME handling package that can simply give me the BODY parts and their corresponding types.

So far I have fetched the body structure and went through the documentation for IMAP FETCH. I have code for extracting text from the text section, but I am getting no where with parsing body structure.

Comment: Are you asking for library recommendations? Those are off-topic here. If not, can you [edit] your question and add a [mcve]?